# Count number of values per time period

Tags: r

I have a dataframe like:

| Month | id_product |
| --- | --- |
| 2020_05 | 0_0 |
| 2020_06 | 0_22 |
| 2020_06 | 0_22 |
| 2021_01 | 2_52 |
| 2023_02 | 0_0 |
| 2023_02 | 0_12 |

I  would like to get the amount of each product sold each month, like:

| Month | 0_0 | 0_12 | 0_22 | 2_52 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020_05 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 2020_06 | 0 | 0 | 2 | 0 |
| 2021_01 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 2023_02 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 |

So I can find the best/worst sellers per month, quarters, years, etc.

I have tried several methods (aggregate, etc.), but I did not find the way to do it with the 70 000 transactions and 3 000 id products of my database.
Maybe I am not taking the issue by the right side.
I am looking for the right strategy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```r
df <- structure(list(Month = c("2020_05", "2020_06", "2020_06", "2021_01", 
"2023_02", "2023_02"), id_product = c("0_0", "0_22", "0_22", 
"2_52", "0_0", "0_12")), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = "data.frame")

library(data.table)
setDT(df)

dcast(df, Month ~ id_product, fun.aggregate = length)
#> Key: <Month>
#>      Month   0_0  0_12  0_22  2_52
#>     <char> <int> <int> <int> <int>
#> 1: 2020_05     1     0     0     0
#> 2: 2020_06     0     0     2     0
#> 3: 2021_01     0     0     0     1
#> 4: 2023_02     1     1     0     0
```

<sup>Created on 2022-01-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: It does work. Thank you! I cannot cast a vote as my reputation does not allow me to.

Answer (score 1):

in Base R:

```
a <- table(df)
b <- cbind(Month = rownames(a), as.data.frame.matrix(a))
rownames(b) <- NULL
b

    Month 0_0 0_12 0_22 2_52
1 2020_05   1    0    0    0
2 2020_06   0    0    2    0
3 2021_01   0    0    0    1
4 2023_02   1    1    0    0
```

Comment: Great, does exactly what I was looking for. Thank you! I cannot cast a vote as my reputation does not allow me to.

Comment: @Bruno You can accept the answer to close the question

Answer (score 0):

```
library(data.table)
```

## dummy data

```
df <- data.table(month = c('2020_01', '2020_01', '2020_01', '2021_02', '2021_02', '2021_02')
             , id_product = c(1,2,2,1,1,2)
             ); df

     month id_product
1: 2020_01          1
2: 2020_01          2
3: 2020_01          2
4: 2021_02          1
5: 2021_02          1
6: 2021_02          2
```

## summary - each product's quantity sold per month

```
x <- df[, .(q = .N), .(month, id_product)][]

     month id_product q
1: 2020_01          1 1
2: 2020_01          2 2
3: 2021_02          1 2
4: 2021_02          2 1
```

## max q sold - best selling product per month

```
x[x[, .I[q == max(q)], .(month)]$V1]

     month id_product q
1: 2020_01          2 2
2: 2021_02          1 2
```

Comment: Thank you. When I try your code, it works, but when I try with my dataframe, I get : `Error in drop && !has.j : invalid 'x' type in 'x && y '``. I don't see the difference between your df and mine (same column titles, etc.). Actually, the only difference seems to be  the ' _ ' in the id_product column. I think that is triggering the error, but I cannot understand why.

Comment: Make sure your dataframe is a datatable. Check by `class(df)`
if it isn't a datatable then use `setDT`

Comment: I could fix the issue following your advice. Thank you! I cannot cast a vote as my reputation does not allow me to. I really like this site, I spend hours on it everyday.

Comment: Glad could help. Happier still you like StackO. No worries about vote for now. Try help others also :)